# How to create a multiple page pdf using Spring and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a requirement where in I am creating 2 templates for example template1.html and template2.html and I need to create a pdf from the above template. 
Now, my PDF file should be like 
- First page is always the template1.html
- Second page would be template2.html

I basically have to create a 2 page pdf. 
on some condition it could be more pages as well but any pages after page 1 would be of type template2.html with different data.

Could anyone suggest me a way to combine multiple template files under one pdf.

Answer (score 0):

With iText you can easily convert html contents to PDF format.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf

Once you generate different pdf files you can merge them using PDFWriter
https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for something specific with Thymeleaf.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Please share if you figured it out how to achieve this using thymeleaf. @VarunDamani

Comment: @AnshulKabra I couldn't find anything with Thymeleaf to support my requirement. I used Apache PDFBox and Boxable instead. I used them because they were open source.